# Codeigniter site only shows one included view

Tags: php, linux, windows, codeigniter, xampp

I just uploaded my codeigniter website to the live server, and then i had to take care of some errors that popped up. The problem i am running into now however is quite strange. My main "Page" controller compiles several views together to construct a page. For example, i add the header, navbar, content and the footer to the page through my controller, but only the content view makes it through. Here is the main function that constructs my page in the Page controller:

```
public function view($page = 'home')
    {

        if (!file_exists(APPPATH . '/views/pages/' . $page . '.php')) {
            // If the page does not exist
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter of title

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data); // Load the Header
        $this->load->view('templates/navbar', $data); // Load the Navbar
        $this->load->view('pages/' . $page); // Load the defined page
        $this->load->view('templates/footer'); // Load the footer
    }
```

The server i uploaded it to is a Linux server, which has a very high case sensitivity. I had to rename my controller from page.php to Page.php just for codeigniter to find the view i was trying to construct. Though my "missing view" error has been solved, only my page makes it through my controller, and not the files that are inside the templates folder.

The website works perfecly fine on my windows Xampp server, but does not work on this online environment. I checked all my edited files for lower/uppercase issues, but could not find any. As far as i could find out, the codeigniter files should natively support both linux and windows. Does anyone know what i have done wrong? I am quite new to codeigniter.

Comment: Did you edit your base URL in config file?

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://www.mydomain.nl'
Should be correct right?

Comment: do the files you're trying to display have the correct permissions? i.e. can apache read the files?

Comment: They were 644, and i switched them to 755. Since that didn't fix it, i decided to permit all files 755 access, but without luck.

Comment: Just tried uploading to a different webhost. Sadly, it did not help.

Comment: Could there be a fatal error in the view that is stopping the page from rendering? And you are not seeing errors because they are not displaying on production?

Comment: Wow there is a whole lot going on on that page that i have not seen before i uploaded it. How can a new server screw up so much of the config. It seems that something just breaks in the codeigniter core files. It cannot connect to the database, it cannot start a session, headers are already sent etc.

Answer (score 0):

Linux is case sensitive as you have mentioned but that is not causing your issue.

Are you trying to embed the pages dynamically?
If so then you can try this approach.  Pass the page as a variable.  *I would build a master template instead of your current approach as it would make embedding easier.*

#### Controller

```
function view(){
    $this->load->view('pages', array(
        'page_view' => $page
    ));
}
```

#### Pages.php

```
<?php echo $page_view; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily add the following to the top of your `index.php` file to make sure all errors are displayed. **Be sure to remove this when you go live!**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Usually I do the following things when it comes to file naming in Ubuntu.

- All my filenames are lowercase like so `page.php`, `templates/header.php` and so on...
- Class names like so: `class Page {}`
- I always refer to my classes, libraries, views and any module for that matter in **lowercase** throughout my code, like:

  ```
  # file: application/models/my_model.php
  class My_model extends CI_Model {}

  # file: application/controllers/page.php

  # loaded this way:
  $this->load->model('my_model');

  # and used this way:
  $this->my_model->some_model_function();
  ```

For database errors, check your new server mysql user config. And you are probably getting `headers are already sent` errors because an error occurred before `session_start()` appears in code, which means, the error was echoed, and as the header is sent before the first `echo` statement, you cannot start session. This goes away if you fix the corresponding error.